# Cannot Load Video from S3 AWS( Android Studio )

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-studio, amazon-s3, video-streaming

I'm trying to load video from my S3 AWS service.
The problem is that every time I try to load video, I'm getting:

```
D/MediaPlayer﹕ Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side 

E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -2147483648)

E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1,-2147483648)

D/VideoView﹕ Error: 1,-2147483648
```

I don't know if it's problem with permissions? This is my Android Code:

```
            AWSCredentials myCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("my-key", "secret-key");
            AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(myCredentials);
            GeneratePresignedUrlRequest request = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest("-", "AndroidCommercial.3gp");

            objectURL = s3client.generatePresignedUrl(request);
            videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

            getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
            MediaController mediaCtrl;
            mediaCtrl = new MediaController( MainActivity.this );
            mediaCtrl.setMediaPlayer(videoview);
            videoview.setMediaController(mediaCtrl);
            Uri clip = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(objectURL));
            videoview.setVideoURI(clip);
            videoview.requestFocus();

            videoview.start();
```

I'm not sure if it's problem with AWS or my APP... I've created user with  AmazonS3FullAccess policy. I can download that file with AWS chrome extension. Can anyone help me?

Best Regards, Mateusz

Comment: Try print out the presigned url and load it in a browser to see whether it works.

Comment: Already did it and it worked, but it doesn't work in VideoView... Don't know what's the problem :(

Comment: Interesting. Have you tried to play the downloaded video as file in media player? I want to figure out whether it's the file is corrupted or S3/SDK has some issue.

Comment: Yes, MediaPlayer plays it without any problem :( So I don't know what's the problem here. I can't even watch public video like: https://s3.amazonaws.com/-name-/test.3gp

Comment: Are you able to play any video from the web with video player?

Comment: Yes, I can play videos from other servers

Comment: I made a sample app myself. I uploaded a mp4 video to s3 and made it publicly accessible (not necessary though as you use presigned url). Then I set the uri exactly the same way. The video was able to play.

You said you downloaded the video in chrome. On desktop or in Android? Can your android device access S3? Try listBucket or upload a video within your Android app.

Comment: In Android, I've download video in normal Android web Browser. Could you provide me your sample APP? Maybe I should try to play it on another Android device...